# Activerecord query .where string as number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have record in my db where there is a time element which is a number stored as a string. 
I'd like to run a where query where I check if the number is greater than x
e.g.

```
Recording.where("recording_duration_ms.to_i > 60000")
```

Sure it must be simple to do...

Comment: Why is `recording_duration_ms` stored as a string? Wouldn't it make more sense to fix your schema rather than kludging around it?

Comment: Going with @muistooshort, you could write a migration task to get all values, change column type (drop and add), then insert the strings as ints.  I wouldn't be surprised if has larger implications than you are seeing now.  From there you can use `Client.where("recording_duration_to_ms > ?", 60000)`

Comment: You should store integers as integers in a database

Comment: Have some sympathy with the comments above. It just happened that the return from an external API has the value as a string, so I'd have to be aware that I'd changed the data type if I was cross checking against the values returned by the API. Which I don't suppose is impossible,just a bit annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfecting the answer that @Alex Peachey gave...

To [avoid SQL injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures), you want to use either `?` or `hash`

`Recording.where("CAST(recording_duration_ms AS INT) > ?", 60000)`

or

`Recording.where("CAST(recording_duration_ms AS INT) > :duration", duration: 60000)`

Comment: You are right on the SQL injection part. Never put your variables into the query unless you are 100% sure.

Comment: While it's good to avoid SQL injection when building your queries, there was no injection possibility because the `60000` was not variable. If it was variable and being interpolated, then yes definitely avoid injection.

Comment: "check if the number is greater than x" in the question sounded like a variable, but I guess you are correct - the example did not contain a variable. In any case though, hardcoded queries are boring. :) Today it's 60000 and tomorrow it's something else. The code should be able to handle passing in a parameter for the value to query against.

Answer (score 4):

Most SQL databases allow you to `CAST` values to different data types. The query most likely to do what you want is:

`Recording.where('CAST(recording_duration_ms AS INT) > 60000')`

Answer (score 0):

This works with the PostgreSQL, at least

```
Recording.where('recording_duration_ms::int > ?', 60000)
```

Answer (score -2):

PSQL stores everything as a string, so you need single quotes around 60000:

Recording.where("recording_duration_ms.to_i > '60000'")

(I think)

Comment: (1) PostgreSQL does not store everything as strings. (2) `.to_i` is a Ruby method call, not SQL. (3) String comparisons don't work like numeric comparisons, `'2' > '10'` for example is true.